# What is 'spit in the hole' referencing to?

Tags: reference

> **Spit in the hole**, man, and tune again.

[Taming of the Shrew Act 3 Scene 1](http://shakespeare.mit.edu/taming_shrew/full.html)

What is **Spit in the hole** referencing  to in this text?

Comment: Maybe he means the musician was singing badly and playing badly, and he should get rid of some mucous by spitting, tune his instrument, and start fresh.

Answer (score 1):

The translation indicates it is a command to lubricate the tuning apparatus as a reprimand for it being out of tune

> LUCENTIO (as CAMBIO): Spit on [the tuning-peg](http://nfs.sparknotes.com/shrew/page_114.html), man, and try again

Comment: If you spit on a wooden (lute's ?) tuning peg, it swells slightly and grips the hole more strongly. This stops the tension of the string from turning the peg back and de-tuning itself. (It's the opposite of "lubrication", perhaps :-)

Comment: Perhaps, but then perhaps that is intentional. in that scene he (the speaker) reprimands the man with the lute for not knowing what he is trying to teach and they are competing to win the affection of a singular student (the shrews sister). He may be purposely misleading or mocking him to make his rival lose face.